How to actually use torch._constrain_as_size with real models (for onnx conversion purposes)?
I have a model I would like to convert to onnx. The model is based on torchaudio.models.Conformer:
class ConformerSpeechRecognizer(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 kernel_size,
                 ffn_dim: int,
                 feature_vector_size: int,
                 hidden_layer_size: int,
                 num_layers: int,
                 num_heads: int,
                 dropout: float,
                 depthwise_conv_kernel_size: int,
                 vocabulary_size: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.vocabulary_size = vocabulary_size
        self.cnn_ = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features=feature_vector_size),
            torch.nn.Conv1d(
                in_channels=feature_vector_size,
                out_channels=hidden_layer_size,
                bias=False,
                kernel_size=(kernel_size,),
                padding='same'
            ),
            torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(num_features=hidden_layer_size)
        )
        self.conformer_ = torchaudio.models.Conformer(
            input_dim=hidden_layer_size,
            num_heads=num_heads,
            num_layers=num_layers,
            ffn_dim=ffn_dim,
            depthwise_conv_kernel_size=depthwise_conv_kernel_size,
            dropout=dropout
        )
        self.proba_appoximator_ = torch.nn.Linear(
            in_features=hidden_layer_size,
            out_features=vocabulary_size
        )
    def forward(self, inputs: torch.Tensor, input_lenghts: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        hidden_states = torch.nn.functional.gelu(self.cnn_(inputs.permute(0, 2, 1)))
        hidden_states, _ = self.conformer_(hidden_states.permute(0, 2, 1), input_lenghts)
        output_logits = self.proba_appoximator_(hidden_states)
        return output_logits

When I try to convert the model to onnx using torch.onnx.dynamo_export:
model = torch.load("my_model.pt", map_location=torch.device('cpu')).eval()
onnx_program = torch.onnx.dynamo_export(model.cpu(), inputs=input, input_lenghts=lengths)

I get the following error:

line 1515, in get_fake_value
raise UserError(  # noqa: TRY200 torch._dynamo.exc.UserError: Tried to use data-dependent value in the subsequent computation. This
can happen when we encounter unbounded dynamic value that is unknown
during tracing time.  You will need to explicitly give hint to the
compiler. Please take a look at constrain_as_value OR
constrain_as_size APIs.  It appears that you're trying to get a value
out of symbolic int/float whose value is data-dependent (and thus we
do not know the true value.)  The expression we were trying to
evaluate is Eq(i0, 250) (unhinted: Eq(i0, s0)).  Scroll up to see
where each of these data-dependent accesses originally occurred. For
more information about this error, see:
https://pytorch.org/docs/main/generated/exportdb/index.html#constrain-as-size-example

According to the error hint, I've tried several things for setting constraints which idea looks like putting the following lines in model "forward" method:
torch._constrain_as_size(inputs.size(dim=0), 1, 100)
torch._constrain_as_size(inputs.size(dim=1), 1, 250)
torch._constrain_as_size(input_lenghts.size(dim=0), 1, 100)

Naturally, that doesn't work and returns

can only constrain range for SymInt

How can I put constraints on my model for conversion?
Is it possible to do proper conversion with the model that has been already trained without constraints (just change model declaration script like I'm trying to do above)?
